# bootstrap col is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am expecting the divs to be aligned horizontally,, but they are stacked one below the other. Why is this happening.

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>5000</h3></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>5000</h3></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>5000</h3></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hycdvmhn/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your screen resolution?
It is working in screens with 992px or wider..

Maybe you could use `col-sm-4` (768px or wider) or even `col-xs-4` (no min-width) based on your needs..

Comment: col-sm-4 worked. but dont understand why. 
 
I am watching this in a screen resolution of 1440 X 900 and the browsers chrome and firefox are in maximized position.

Comment: you sure the right container (the one that displays your code) is wider than 992px? maybe try to inspect it

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

You are likely viewing it in a screen not wider than `992px` which is the breakpoint for the `-md-` size.

I can see your fiddle fine on my `1920px` wide screen. See below. If you drag the vertical bar in the middle and make it smaller, then it will stack over one another when you get to less than `992px`.

[image]

Comment: I am watching this in a screen resolution of 1440 X 900 and the browsers chrome and firefox are in maximized position.

Comment: Then maybe your bootstrap CSS is not being rendered or included? See the gridsystem breakpoints here. http://getbootstrap.com/css/  I saw your comment on the selected answer that `-sm-` worked. So if that did, it means your css is being used, which implies the size of your browser window is `<992px`.